# Remix not loading in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: solidity, remix, ide

For some reason i cant access the online Remix IDE. http://remix.ethereum.org

it gives me a blank page with a logo. Tried to access from Firefox, Chrome and Edge aswell as disabling all extensions including adblocker but all three show me the same screen. Am I missing something?

[image: Screenshot of remix]

Comment: It does work here, perhaps it was a temporary glitch. Try again, checking browser console for some error.

Comment: try turning off your wifi (or network) and turn it on again.

Comment: seems like today is working fine

Answer (score 0):

An issue is given there :
https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/issues/122

Execute into console :

```
fetch('https://remix.ethereum.org/assets/version.json', { cache: "no-store" }).then(response => {
  response.text().then(function (data) {
    const version = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(`Loading Remix ${version.version}`);
    createScriptTag(`polyfills.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'module');
    if (version.mode === 'development') {
      createScriptTag(`vendor.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'module');
      createScriptTag(`runtime.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'module');
    }
    createScriptTag(`main.${version.version}.${version.timestamp}.js`, 'text/javascript');
  });
});
```